# I have a java desktop application I developed. After I install it into the clients file how can I prevent that they copy to people

Tags: java, desktop-application

The setup folder has the .exe, jar file, libraries and the structure of the database to install on the sql management server. dilemma is I don't want them to copy the setup file and give it to other people.

Comment: If they really wanted your application setup, they could still attempt to decompile the Java code

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have just a few customers? The easiest way would be a personalised license file where the name of the license holder is displayed, e.g. when starting the application.

If you sign (e.g. gpg or x.509) the certificate you can prevent usage without license.

Comment: how can I do that, sorry this is my first app to develop. My app is totally offline tho it only uses a database connection which is also offline